# XMLHttpRequest Object : can't retrieve data from XML using responseXML

Tags: xml, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to get responseXML from JSP which has XML content.But not able to get node values from the responseXML Object.Even the root node is shown as null.

I am using IE8.
Below is the code i am using.

```
function function2(){
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4){
        if(xhr.status==200){
        var xhrResponse=xhr.responseXML;    
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhrResponse==null);
            alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            var theRoot = xhrResponse.documentElement;
            alert(theRoot);
            alert(theRoot.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

            alert(xhrResponse.getElementsByTagName("Name").length);     
        }
    }
}

xhr.open("GET", "jspXML.jsp" ,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");   
xhr.send();
}
```

Server Side Scripting:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%response.setContentType("text/xml"); %>
<College>
<Student>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Age>10</Age>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Name>C</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
</Student>
</College>
```

From alert messages ,found that responseXML is Not null and it is an {object].But the root element (using documentElement) is null.

But responseText is showing properly.

1.Is this behavior browser-dependent ?

2.When i googled this issue,many solutions suggetsed to set the request header as "text/xml".As per my understanding ,the responseXML is retrieved using response header.So,do i need really need to set request header or setting response header is the correct way?

Can anyone tell whether i am missing something?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, if you look in your javascript console or debugger, is that the xml document is invalid.  The XML declaration has to be the first thing in the document, but your document begins with whitespace in the form of a line feed between the `@page` directive and the xml declaration.  The solution is very simple:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<College>
<Student>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Age>10</Age>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Name>C</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
</Student>
</College>
```

Now there's no line feed between the directive and the declaration.  Also note that the scriptlet to set the content type is not necessary - the `@page` directive has already set it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Tap for quick response ,It worked...And also i commented out xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml"); part.Still it is giving correct result.So i suppose setting Request Header is not really not required as technically i am sending null value alsong with HTTP request